# Convert Raw CSV Line into Array

Tags: go

The other suggestions were either in Java, or didn't take this into account (that I found).

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
for err == nil {
    line, err = Readln(reader)
    record := strings.Split(line, ",")
    fmt.Println(len(record), line)
}
```

Using this loop, I'm efficiently reading through my CSV file, however, there is a problem with `Split` when it encounters a row that has commas inside the intended value. For example, `"Fake Company USA, Inc.",`
`strings.Split` will split on that comma inside the string as well.

Is there a way to Split on the intended comma here? Such as, a comma with 0 white space around it, or a comma that isn't surrounded by quotes?

Note: I'm going the raw method becausethe csv readers I was using before didn't play well with large files, so I'm resorting to bufio for processing sake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason you wouldn't use the built in `encoding/csv` package?  As long as you use `.Read` and not `.ReadAll` the performance should be the same as reading line by line and trying to split yourself.

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "io"
    "fmt"
)

reader := csv.NewReader(file)

for {
    records, err := reader.Read()   
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(records)
}
```

Comment: I was reading that this encoding has some pretty heavy performance hits, and speed is absolutely necessary for me here. Will this method break on 50k rows? Or 500 million?

Comment: Also, this snippet ended up giving me `2020/02/18 00:09:39 record on line 3: wrong number of fields`, does it handle parsing of quotes, etc?

Comment: If your lines have variable number of fields, you need to set `reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1`

Comment: And this shouldn't break on anything that your string splitting method wouldn't break on - it's still reading a file line by line.  I've used this exact method on a csv with ~250,000 rows, and it performed fine.  For 500 million I can't say for sure, but in theory it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: but make sure your `file` is buffered, don't use `ioutil.ReadFile`

Comment: This seems to be working, but I'm trying to figure out why I'm reaching in io.EOF after the first line on a larger file. But that may be unrelated. Thank you!

Comment: @Volker I'm new to this and I don't even know how to run benchmarks, but thanks for that.

Comment: @dave thanks again for the help, the EOF error was because my CSV file was malformed. I'm going to try a large GB file tonight but so far it's handled ~150mb quickly!